# Fluent NHibernate: LEFT OUTER JOIN ... AND Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the next Fluent NHibernate query using QueryOver:

```
IQueryOver<Task> query = session
    .QueryOver<Task>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Subject, () => subject, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .JoinAlias(() => subject.Localizations, () => localization, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Where(() => localization.Language.Id == languageId || localization.Language.Id == null);
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId)
```

This performs the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks left outer join Subjects on Tasks.SubjectId = Subjects.IdAsignatura 
left outer join Languages on Subjects.SubjectId=Languages.SubjectId
WHERE Tasks.UserId = xxx 
and (Languages.LanguageId = yyy or Languages.LanguageId = is null)
```

I would like to avoid the last line using "LEFT OUTER JOIN ... AND" like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks left outer join Subjects on Tasks.SubjectId = Subjects.IdAsignatura 
left outer join Languages on Subjects.SubjectId=Languages.SubjectId AND Languages.LanguageId = yyy
WHERE Tasks.UserId = xxx
```

Is there a way to perform "LEFT OUTER JOIN ... AND" Fluent NHibernate queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one overload of the CreateAlias:

```
/// <param name="path">Lambda expression returning association path</param>
/// <param name="alias">Lambda expression returning alias reference</param>
/// <param name="joinType">Type of join</param>
/// <param name="withClause">Additional criterion for the SQL on clause</param>
/// <returns>
/// criteria instance
/// </returns>
IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> JoinAlias<U>(Expression<Func<U>> path
     , Expression<Func<U>> alias, JoinType joinType
     , ICriterion withClause);
```

That means, that we can pass the Restriction from WHRE into ON clause

```
/// instead of this
.JoinAlias(() => subject.Localizations, () => localization, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.Where(() => localization.Language.Id == languageId 
          || localization.Language.Id == null);

/// We can use this:
.JoinAlias(() => subject.Localizations, () => localization, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin
            // the 4th param is appended to ON clause with AND operator
            , Restrictions.Where(() => localization.Language.Id == languageId)
)
```

The **withClause** could be injected into the ON part of our SELECT, but always with AND operator. So it can only apply **more** restrictions than the basic mapped relation.

Comment: Thak you very much. Your answer is correct, but I think that "|| localization.Language.Id == null" is not needed with LeftOuterJoin.

Comment: Mostlikely - correct. I tried to show the HOW TO... so you are right... ;) Just wanted to show what is **the way** with NHibernate and not thought through the real content. Great if that helped. Enjoy Nhibernate @Freerider ;) *(updated the answer as well)*